# Cookie values not being sent in POST request from SWF

Tags: php, cookies, flash

I have a SWF file which allows a user to upload files on my website. That SWF sends a POST request to `upload.php` on my server, thus uploading the file.

But before it does so, at upload.php I wanna make sure that the person who is doing this is `signed in`. For this currently, I check the `SID cookie value` sent in the request headers and check an entry against that SID value in my database (i store sessions in database). I works well for `chrome` but fails in `firefox` as it doesn't send any cookie headers when request is generated by the SWF.

How should I go about it. Thanks for help.

Headers sent in Chrome

```
Content-Length: 355894
Origin: http://localhost 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------ei4Ij5ae0ae0ei4Ef1Ef1KM7GI3Ef1 
Accept: */* 
Referer: http://localhost/home Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 
Cookie: PHPSSID = 238e320eewbjdbew923e092ejhwbjhwebd
```

Headers sent in FireFox

```
Accept: text/* 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------GI3Ef1Ef1ae0GI3cH2Ef1Ef1cH2KM7 
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash 
Host: localhost 
Content-Length: 355894 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of Chrome, but not a Bug of FireFox. Uploading SWF's must explictly send browser cookies. Look at FancyUpload starting from version 3.0.

Also note, PHP with suhosin can remove session variables if User-Agent header is not equal to the browsers. This called 'Session Fixtion'. So Uploading SWF's must send browsers User-Agent during requests too (or just disable suhosin patch).